# Drop down site selector in Data Explorer lists IT Security, not Information Security

Tags: bug, data-explorer, site-name

In the site selector on Data Explorer, Security Stack Exchange is still listed as IT Security, not Information Security.

[image]

Comment: Data explorer is whole different story, please start a new separate bug report for it. As for "those migration choices" what do you mean? Where you see this? Link and screenshots would really help. :)

Comment: Once I am at a device that can do that I will. The migrate dialogue is the standard one. If I want to migrate a post, I start typing Security in the drop down.

Comment: Or I assume it is the standard one - it may be mod only. Haven't been able to check yet

Comment: Only moderators can choose any site, retagged.

Comment: Thanks. Once I finish traveling I can clean up and add screenshots

Comment: Updated as it appears I'm a complete moron - I am only seeing this on Data Explorer now. So maybe I was seeing things this morning

Comment: hmm... the names should arrive from API so it's kind of weird. Need Tim Stone!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, not on Data Explorer, they're pulled from the Sites table. And that meta data needs updating, I guess.

Comment: @Tim what is the reason for not using the API for this? Performance?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Various reasons including that, but the most direct is that not all sites available via the API are included in SEDE.

Comment: @Tim I see. So who is updating the meta data you mentioned? A dev, or you somehow?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nick'll have to run something, but I'll talk to him and see if he wants me to just give him an update script.

Comment: @Tim cool, let's hope it'll be done soon - now let's also stop flooding poor Rory's inbox. :-D

Comment: Heh - a surprise once I got back to my hotel and on to wifi :-)

Comment: @TimStone [Community Building is also still listed as Moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261517/sede-should-pick-up-on-changes-to-community-metadata).