# SEDE should pick up on changes to community metadata

Tags: bug, data-explorer

It appears that site meta data isn't updated in SEDE. As an example, Moderators.SE was [renamed](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/197/78) to [Community Building](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com) in December 2014. It is still listed in SEDE as Moderators.SE, as of July 2015.

To search for Community Building data, we need to search the "Moderators" community:

[image: Moderators search]

It is not listed as Community Building:

[image: No community building :(]

Comment: There's also [Information Security](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253588/drop-down-site-selector-in-data-explorer-lists-it-security-not-information-secu) with an obsolete name.

Comment: [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286109/165773) lists nine sites that went through name changes, along with Programmers (renamed to Software Engineering) this makes ten. As far as I can tell 7 of these 10 renames aren't reflected in Data Explorer (names were updated only for Arqade, Mi Yodeya, and Electrical Engineering)

Comment: @gnat well, [this looked promising](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/573011) but it doesn't  stick ...

Comment: @rene I think the actual site names are taken from some mysterious meta file, probably updated manually by Nick. Can't really find the source I saw once, and I might be way off, but if correct really not sure why Sam/Tim chose to use a text file and not, well, database.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, it needs to be updated indeed by Nick because it isn't kept in the [/Migrations](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/tree/master/Migrations) only structure changes are there.

Comment: @rene on second thought, why not using the API to query the site names, even daily just to see if anything changed?

Comment: @ShadowWizard and then what? We can't do anything about it except posting on MSE, bugging Tim in chat and twitter Nick ... anyway most parts of the script needed is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/158100)

Comment: @rene I mean suggesting to Tim to change the code to query the API and get rid of the static text file. Think it's feasible?

Comment: @ShadowWizard hmm, that Sites table and its usage needs to be refactored then because now it holds both technical and *business*  data. Most scary is that a stable key is missing in the [Sites API endpoint](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=500&filter=default&run=true). So you'll probably end up adding rows to the sites table while you should have been updating.